# Helpers vs Extensions in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

What is the different between Helpers class and Extension class in Ruby on Rails ?

A friend tell me that Extension is object related class, that mean Extension will define the method for that object instance.
And Helpers is view related class, the method defined in helper class should be use in the View with similar name with the class.

Answer (score 1):

Extensions are used to extend the functionality of object methods that already exist by default in rails. For example the .blank? method. If you want that default method to have extra functionality you would extend that method:

```
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/core_ext/object/blank'

# Customize your extension here ...
```

When you created your own classes (User Class, Post Class, etc.) you can add methods to that class using the helper class. If you want to log in a user:

```
#Session Helper Class

  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end
```

You wouldn't use a Helper Class when you want to interact with the Models data. For that you can define methods in the Model Class.